# how can i get category/serie value from jqplot barchart in a javascript function called inside extender primefaces attribute?

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

i have the following code:

```
<p:barChart id="bar" extender="extBar"
        value="#{primeBean.findBarModel('simpleBarChart')}" />

<script>
                function ext() {

                        }       
</script>
```

Will be renderized the values:

```
[
        [[5,1], [1,2], [3,3], [4,4]],
        [[4,1], [7,2], [1,3], [2,4]]
]
```

How can i get the category/serie value inside ext function ? Is there an element that i can get these values inside ext ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and it's very easy. Add a `widgetVar` attribute to your `<p:barChart` this way :

```
<p:barChart widgetVar="myWidget" ... />
```

The you can access the data in javascript using `myWidget.cfg.data`. You'll get an array of array that you can read using regular js.

You can test it online in the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/barChart.jsf), open a javascript console if your browser has one and type : `widget_basic.cfg.data`